# How to check for multiple levels of attributes without wearing out keyboard?

Tags: python-3.x

```
if hasattr(some_object, "some_property") and 
    hasattr(some_object.some_property, "some_other_property") and 
    hasattr(some_object.some_property.some_other_property, "some_final_property"):
```

really stinks.  Is there a better way to do this?

Do I just try to access it and then catch the exception?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. Try to get the nested property and catch the exception:

```py
try:
    prop = some_obj.some_property.some_other_property.some_final_property
except AttributeError:
    # handle exception
else:
    do_something_with(prop)
```

If the objects are dictionaries, there are some helpers like `toolz` package's [`get_in()`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.get_in) that you might find useful:

```py
prop = get_in(['some_property', 'some_other_property', 'some_final_property'], some_obj)
```